# function to sort rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which filters a row based on the part number.

```
df= sets[sets['num_parts'] == 11695]
df
```

[image]

Now, i want to write a function where i can simply call a function and pass set_num as a string and return the rows.

Here is what I have tried. This is giving me an error.

```
def select_set_row(df):
    return display(df.iloc['set_num'])
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: Please post a data sample as text so that we can replicate your problem

Answer (score 0):

`iloc` is integer-location based indexing. You should use `df['set_num'].iloc[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly not a function, but you can create similar function.

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'num_parts': [132, 234, 345, 578, 462, 222]})

print(df)
```

list of `num_parts`:

```
num_parts = df['num_parts'].tolist()
```

Outputing dataframe for each `num_parts`:

```
for parts in num_parts:
    print(df[df['num_parts'] == parts])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort by this function :

```
def select_set_numparts(num_parts):
    return sets[sets['num_parts'] == num_parts]
```